# Tietze extension theorem for complex valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Why is this theorem always only stated for real valued functions, and not for complex valued functions?

Thanks.

Comment: The most general form has all "absolute extensors" as the codomain. $\mathbb{R}$ is one, any closed interval like $[0,1]$ is too, and so are all powers of the reals, including the square, i..e $\mathbb{C}$. See e.g. [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolute_neighbourhood_extensor) for some more info.

Answer (score 6):

The [wikipedia article on Tietze's Extension Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) mentions that one can replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}^I$ for any index set $I$.  Taking $\# I = 2$ -- and, of course, using that $\mathbb{C}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$! -- we get the result you are asking about.  So to my mind this is a standard reference which includes the version of the theorem you are asking about.

The version for $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions follows immediately from the version for $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions, because a function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous iff its real and imaginary parts $\Re f, \Im f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous: this is the universal property of the direct product.  So you can apply the $\mathbb{R}$-valued Tietze Extension Theorem to each component to get the $\mathbb{C}$-valued version.  (This argument works verbatim with $\mathbb{R}^2$ replaced by $\mathbb{R}^I$ for any set $I$: it is again the universal property of the direct product.)

Answer (score 3):

Since the theorem uses only the topology of $\mathbb R$ and not in any way the multiplicative structure, $\mathbb C$ is basically the same as $\mathbb R^2$. But the theorem easily generalises to $\mathbb R^n$: just extend each component separately.