# Application of Riesz representation theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Suppose the following situation. We have linear functional $\ell$ on the space $H(\mathbb{C}^n)$ of entire function and wish to find a representation for $l$ with integration against a complex Borel measure \mu with compact support. i.e:

$$\ell(f)=\int f d\mu\quad \forall f\in H(\mathbb{C}^n).$$

Well, my text suggests to use Hahn-Banach theorem and then Riesz representation. But I dont rly know how. Should $l$ be extended to $C(\mathbb{C}^n)$? And which version of Riesz representation theorem is to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you extend $l$ to $\lambda \in C(\mathbb{C}^n)^\ast$. Then, since $\lambda$ is continuous, there is a compact $K \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ with

$$\lvert \lambda(f)\rvert \leqslant M\cdot \max \left\{\lvert f(z)\rvert : z \in K\right\},$$

and you use the Riesz representation theorem for continuous linear functionals on $C(K)$ (by Tietze's extension theorem, the restriction $\rho \colon C(\mathbb{C}^n) \to C(K)$ is surjective, and the kernel of $\rho$ is contained in $\ker\lambda$, so the induced functional on $C(K)$ is well-defined and uniquely determined by $\lambda$), which gives you a representing Borel measure $\mu$ on $K$.

Comment: Thanks alot! How can I interpret $\lambda$ as a functional on $C(K)$? Is it because I can (continously) extend continous functions from K to $\mathbb{C}^n$ and then use $\lambda$ on the extension?

Comment: Yes, precisely (should have mentioned Tietze's theorem too, sorry).

Comment: Ok, so far so good:) But for complex-valued bounded linear functionals I only know the version of Riesz representation theorem from Rudin,6.19. The space mentioned there is the space $C_0(K)$ of continuous functions 'vanishing at infinity', and clearly $C(K)$ is not such a space. Do you happen to know a reference on your version? All other version I know require $\lambda$ to be a positive functional.

Comment: It is such a space. For compact $K$, you have $C(K) = C_0(K)$, since given any $f\in C(K)$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a compact set $M\subset K$ (namely $K$ itself) such that $\lvert f(z)\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $z\notin M$ (vacuously, here). We could however also use the $C_0(U)$ version for an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ by multiplying with a cut-off function $\varphi$ and taking $U = \{ z : \varphi(z) > 0\}$. Then one needs to see that $\{\varphi\cdot f : f \in C(\mathbb{C}^n)\}$ is dense in $C_0(U)$, which isn't too hard either.

Comment: Thanks alot again. I should have seen that they are the same, I didnt use the empty set/all of K correctly. So that makes sense then.

Comment: I'm sry, but I still have more to ask. The thing is: I want the representation to work for my original $f\in H(\mathbb{C}^n)$ as mentioned in the OP. So if $\lambda$ is the extension of $l$ from OP and I restrict my $f$ to $K$ then I can use the functional $\lambda'(f|K)=\lambda(\tilde{(f|K)})$ where $\tilde{(f|K)}$ is an extension of f|K to all of $\mathbb{C}^n$. But this extension doesnt need to be my original $f$, so I havent found an 'integral representation' of $f$ after all. How can I fix that? Can anything be done?

Comment: $\lambda$ (and a fortiori $l$) does only depend on the values on $K$. If $f$ and $g$ coincide on $K$, then $\lambda(f) = \lambda(g)$, since $\sup \{\lvert f(z)-g(z)\rvert : z\in K\} = 0$. The measure you get does indeed represent $l$, you have $$l(f) = \int_K f\,d\mu$$ for all $f\in H(\mathbb{C}^n)$ by construction.

Comment: Thanks, nice:) That makes sense. $\lambda'$ wouldnt be well-defined if not for that fact.

Comment: Another question just arose: These $f$ are all complex-valued, so how does extension work in that case. I only know Tietze for real-valued functions.

Comment: You extend the real and imaginary part of the function. A continuous complex-valued function is just a pair of continuous real-valued functions.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Sry for bothering you, cause I just found the answer via google as well. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313837/tietze-extension-theorem-for-complex-valued-functions

Comment: No problem, @cQQkie, while I'm here, I'm here and notifications don't bother. When I'm not here, I'm away and notifications don't bother ;)