# the complex version of Tietze's theorem can we find an extension that preserves the supremum?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

We have the known [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem). We can easyly extend this theorem for the complex case as we can see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313837/tietze-extension-theorem-for-complex-valued-functions)

My question is, in the complex version of Tietze's theorem can we find an extension that preserves the supremum?

I mean, if $X$ is a normal space and $f: A \to \mathbb C$ is a continuous function defined in a closed subset of $X$, can we find a continuous extension $F: X \to \mathbb C$ such that 
$$ \sup_{x \in X } |F(x)| = \sup_{a \in A} |f(a)|? $$

My attempt:

Writing $f = u + i v$, we can find continuous extensions $\tilde{u},\tilde{v} : X \to \mathbb R$ of $u$ and $v$, resp., such that
$$ \sup_{x \in X } |\tilde{u}(x)| = \sup_{a \in A} |u(a)| \quad \text{and} \quad \sup_{x \in X } |\tilde{v}(x)| = \sup_{a \in A} |v(a)|. $$

Then, if $F = \tilde{u}+i\tilde{v}$ I could only proof that
$$ (\sup_X |F(x)|)^2 \leq (\sup_A |u(a)| )^2 + (\sup_A |v(a)|)^2 $$
and from this point I got stucked.

Help?

Comment: I would try to duplicate a proof of the theorem but do it in $\mathbb R^n$ instead. It's easy to see the continuous extension part holds more generally just by working componentwise, but it might be easier to tweak the proof itself to get the result you desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the most general form is for some called absolute extensors. By definition we can use $X$ as the codomain for Tietze iff it is an absolute extensor (for normal spaces, if you want to be exact). Some more info can be found [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolute_neighbourhood_extensor). These coincide with the absolute retracts (see [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolute_retract_for_normal_spaces)).

$\mathbb{R}$ is an example, but also $[a,b]$ (as a retract of it, which implies we can preserve the sup in the real case too) but also $\mathbb{C}$ and closed balls in it (as retracts).

So if $F: A \to X$ has $R=\sup \{|F(x)|: x \in A\}$ finite, then let $B$ be the zero-centred ball of radius $R$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and note that we have a continuous retraction $r: \mathbb{C} \to B$.

Then we apply Tietze with codomain $\Bbb C$ to get some extension $F'$ and then we use $r \circ F'$ as the sup-preserving extension you want.

Comment: Your F is defined in A and you also denote the supremum of F as A. The ball B, you mean the ball centered in zero?

Comment: @user242964 I edited to clarify.